# what's the meaning of platformID and encodingID in the cmap of OpenType?

Tags: truetype, opentype

The spec( http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cmap.htm ) only have platformID 3(windows) and platformID 1(Mac) and the encodingID in the windows platform. How about other platforms and other encodings beside windows?

I use `ttfdump` to dump one of the adobe fonts and it give me:

```
'cmap' Table - Character to Glyph Index Mapping Table
-----------------------------------------------------
         'cmap' version: 0
         number of encodings: 5
         number of subtables: 3

Encoding   0.    PlatformID:  0
                 EcodingID:   3
                 SubTable: 0, Offset: 0x00000a0e

Encoding   1.    PlatformID:  0
                 EcodingID:   4
                 SubTable: 1, Offset: 0x0000cc26

Encoding   2.    PlatformID:  1
                 EcodingID:  25
                 SubTable: 2, Offset: 0x0000002c

Encoding   3.    PlatformID:  3
                 EcodingID:   1
                 SubTable: 0, Offset: 0x00000a0e

Encoding   4.    PlatformID:  3
                 EcodingID:  10
                 SubTable: 1, Offset: 0x0000cc26
```

So it does have other platforms and encodings but where to find the definitions?

Comment: the actual documentation for them is in http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm

Comment: Yes. Actually the link in the MS doc is broken and the chapter number in the ISO doc is wrong. So I missed that table in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a following table in [Microsoft documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm):

```
 Platform ID  | Platform name | Platform-specific encoding IDs  | Language IDs
 -------------|---------------|---------------------------------|--------------
 0            | Unicode       | Various                         | Various 
 1            | Macintosh     | Script manager code             | Various
 2            | ISO [deprec]  | ISO encoding [deprecated]       | None 
 3            | Windows       | Windows encoding                | Various 
 4            | Custom        | Custom                          | None
```

About non-standard Encoding IDs:

> A new encoding ID for the Unicode platform will be assigned if a new
>   version of Unicode moves characters, in order to properly specify
>   character code semantics.(Because of Unicode stability policies, such
>   a need is not anticipated.) The distinction between Unicode
>   platform-specific encoding IDs 1 and 2 is for historical reasons only;
>   the Unicode Standard is in fact identical in repertoire and encoding
>   to ISO 10646. For all practical purposes in current fonts, the
>   distinctions provided by encoding IDs 0, 1 and 2 are not important,
>   thus these encoding IDs are deprecated.
>
> A new encoding ID for the
>   Unicode platform is also sometimes assigned when new cmap subtable
>   formats are added to the specification, so as to allow for
>   compatibility with existing parsers. For example, when cmap subtable
>   formats 10 and 12 were added to the specification, encoding ID 4 was
>   added as well, and when cmap subtable format 13 was added to the
>   specification, encoding ID 6 was added. The cmap subtable formats
>   listed in the table above are the only ones that may be used for the
>   corresponding encoding ID.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the text that says that more information is in the name table documentation, over at http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm, which contains the (long) lists of which encodings and languages each platform supports.